# Canonical Way to Delete a Vector Allocated on The Heap in C++17

Tags: c++, performance, vector, stl, heap-memory

I have searched stack overflow, but it seems the previous answers are potentially outdated, or just not very clear.

My question is the following:

I want to store a huge amount of data in a vector. To do this, I will allocate the vector on the heap as follows:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> *vector = new std::vector<int> (1000000000);
```

Now suppose I use this vector in a large matrix computation. I want to now free it.

What is the canonical way to do this in c++17?

I know that for an array the riff would be as follows:

```
int *arr = new int[1000000000];
delete[] arr
```

What is the equivalent (and most efficient) way to do this for an stl vector?

Comment: Most likely you don't need to allocate the vector in "the heap".

Comment: thanks, in what cases then would allocating a vector on the heap make sense? I was always told to allocate arrays on the heap if they were too big to fit into the stack. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: `std::vector` (usually) uses `new` internally. A vector with millions of elements takes exactly the same global/automatic storage space as a vector with none.

Comment: I can't think of any case. The vector itself is a small object. All the data is allocated in the free store, which is a C++ name for the heap.

Comment: Ok thanks, that I did not know - I guess I will need to read more about the internal workings of a vector. thanks both!

Comment: Actually, you should focus on reading more about C++ fundamentals. You seem to have been under the impression that large vectors take more stack space than small ones, hence they should be `new`ed. You'll be happy to learn that C++ does not work that way. A vector with a billion values takes up as little stack space as a completely empty one. Same goes for lists, maps, etc...

Comment: @ConvexLeopard You were told to allocate **arrays** on the heap. *Vectors* are a different beast. While they are functionally similar, they are vastly different when it comes to memory management (in that vectors do it for you automatically).

Comment: Thanks all, I guess I will try and get a reference book on the STL to increase my knowledge. I do want to learn more about the fundamental workings of the language as it's pretty interesting.

Comment: Take care when looking for resources on the STL. These days STL is usually seen as meaning the container and algorithm libraries in the Standard library. STL used to be it's own thing and technically it still is. The containers and algorithm libraries are "inspired by" the STL, but 25 years has caused more than a little drift.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you. Would you have any recommendations?

Comment: I'm more plumber, I use the Standard Library to put programs together, than deep-diver into the hows of the library. Scott Meyers's Effective STL was very useful to me and probably still useful, but it is almost 20 years out of date.

Comment: thank you! I will take a look at Scott Meyer's book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with `std::vector` is that its data is *always* on the heap.

Hence you don't have to allocate the `std::vector` itself on the heap.

`std::vector` makes use of a principle called RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization), it means that when it's done with memory, it de-allocates it for you.

Hence, doing this is sufficient

```cpp
{
std::vector<int> x{};
for (size_t i = 0; i < 50000; i++) x.push_back(x);
} // x gets out of scope, memory is freed
```

You don't have to manually free the `std::vector`'s memory.

Now, say you'd allocate the `std::vector` itself on the heap, for whatever reason. Then you'd have to use `delete vector;` to free it. In this scenario, I would suggest `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>` though, as it also makes use of the same principle (RAII).

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Would there be any performance differences in using a vector over an array? I am guessing there is a bit more overhead for a vector?

Comment: A `std::array<int, 10>` is faster, and uses less memory total, but (A) its data _is_ wherever the array is, wheras a `vector`'s data is always on the heap, and (B) much more importantly, it can't be resized. Vectors are resizable.
 The resizing is always the important thing. If the count is known at compile time, almost always use a `std::array`. if the count isn't known, use a `std::vector`.

Comment: exactly that ^^

Comment: @JohnkaS Your `push_back()` loop is very inefficient for a large number of elements. You should `reserve()` the `vector`'s memory before entering the loop: `x.reserve(50000);`

Comment: In no way is that relevant to the question. Reproducing minimal examples is important for the sake of the OP understanding what's going. @RemyLebeau